# Goodness of fit for nonlinear model in R

Tags: r, nls

Is there a sensible parallel to R^2 or similar model fit statistics for nonlinear regression with `nls()` in `R`. Is there something implemented in a package? `nlstools` package does not offer such statistic but plenty of useful diagnnostics etc.

Comment: When opening the library I noticed `IMPORTANT NOTICE: Most nonlinear regression models and data set examples related to predictive microbiolgy have been moved to the package 'nlsMicrobio'`--maybe there's a hint?

Comment: Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148469/how-should-one-assess-model-fit-for-non-linear-regression

Comment: A graphical assessment is often adequate.   Assuming `x` is sorted `fm <- nls(y ~ f(x, a, b), start = list(a = 1, b = 1)); plot(y ~ x)); lines(x, fitted(fm))`